# Is there ANY way to connect github pages to a database

Tags: database, github-pages

I understand GitHub hosts static sites, but I'm wondering if it's possible to send and get a JSON file from a data base. Is it possible that I can host another site and get my site to get or send information from it. Or any api that can connect to a server of a different site and "emulate" the functions GitHub doesn't allow for getting or sending information?

Comment: Yes, something on github pages _can_ potentially talk to a different service that can receive and store data if the 3rd party service allows this. Just write an API ? where are you getting stuck on?

Comment: @Evert I have a GitHub for a web game I'm making, I just want to make sure it's possible before I get too far and waste a bunch of time. I want to eventually have a database of JSON files that a client (the GitHub hosted page) can retrieve and send JSON to that again can be retrieved. But I have no clue where to even begin...

Comment: Yes, you _can_ create some kind of API after. You're not painted into a corner. It's hard to know if this is the perfect order of building though, or if github is the best place. Depends a bit on what you're hoping to do with the API

Comment: @Evert That's great. Can you point me in the right direction? Any documentation or other, how I can ask a server hosted in another URL for this, or if you know of any pre-made API I can use or edit?